# New comment flag - 'convert to answer'

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments

Many times I (and you too, probably!) have come across comments on questions that more or less answer the question. [This](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/27580/semi-loud-growling-noise-at-all-speeds) question, for example, OP figured the problem out and was able fix it before any answers were submitted. Nobody wants to gain rep for answers that weren't theirs, so DucatiKiller and others encouraged OP to submit his comment as an answer, but OP never did, thus the question sat on the unanswered list.

Could we create a 'convert to answer' flag for comments, such that the person who really did come up with the answer could get credit and/or rep for it, and remove it from the list? I'm thinking it could be just like close votes - the flag submits the 'covert to answer' suggestion to a mod or to the review queue, and the flaggers/mods/reviewers could have a chance to edit the comment into a more comprehensive answer.

There is of course the possibility that someone who makes an edit of, say 100+ characters, gets half the rep of the upvotes, or maybe it prompts the comment OP to convert the comment manually, and after some arbitrary units of time the comment is submitted from the 'community' and the comment OP misses out on the rep. The main point being - I feel dirty submitting/getting rep for an answer that was not my own, and would like to give credit where it is due.

We could instead create a 'upvote as answer' flag on comments to give the commenter some rep, and once it reached a certain # of upvotes it could be highlighted or converted.

Questions/comments/concerns/ideas/bomb-ass chili recipes are welcome!

Comment: I think this sort of thing has been discussed a lot on the main http://meta.stackexchange.com and the consensus is, if you post a partial answer as a comment, you're voluntarily forfeiting the rep; taking an answer-as-comment and making it into a proper answer is completely fine and deserves rep, it's just polite (not mandatory) to mention the comment if it helped. I'm writing this as a comment because I don't have time to look up the relevant discussions; feel free to write a better answer along these lines! :-)

Comment: @user568458 HAH! I see what you did there. Thanks for the input! I figured I wasn't the first to think of this, but I didn't know about the meta meta site. Thanks!

Comment: Also, if I post a comment instead of an answer, it's because I want it to be a comment, and not an answer. I'd have a big problem if the community had the power to change my intent here.

Answer (score 3):

As userblahblah mentioned in the comments, this has been discussed and dismissed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51899/allow-converting-comments-to-answers), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128311/add-a-convert-comment-to-answer-button), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109771/ability-to-convert-an-answer-to-a-comment-and-comment-to-an-answer), and probably other places. The consensus seems to be what useryadayada said, and that if it's a comment, it's too short for an answer.

So, never mind! Good talk, guys!   :P

Comment: It seems like what happens here, at least, is that people start to offer ideas and/or trouble shooting tips in comments – perhaps because we don't have enough to go on to start a really valid answer. Then as information and feedback accumulates it becomes clear that we have an answer. Convert to answer seems like a good thing, here at least.

Comment: @dlu I agree, but in that case it may not be clear which post should get the 'covert' vote. Maybe an option to post as 'community' and compile the information?

Comment: Take turns and just make it happen? I'm not against newish users getting the points on the answers. I'd just ask they state at the beginning of the answer something to the affect of, "*This answer was a conversion from comments listed in the original question*" or some such. I've actually done it like that before. It keeps the information from the question on the site, while also closing the question in the process. If the newbie answerer gets some points, then it's a triple win situation.

Comment: I really like the useryadayada bit.